# Zxing: how to update the UI(result view) after handleDecodeInternally() function

Tags: android, user-interface, zxing

As an interest, i am studying the Zxing android related routine, now one question block me for  several hours, it is: How does CaptureActivity update the UI(result view) after handler the decoded contents which is done in function handleDecodeInternally() ??

I search this question through stackoverflow but got no similar one, i know it's just a simple problem while i do not see it.

I am a newcomer for android and Zxing, so i am blocked with this simple question here, can anyone give me some hint??  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`handleDecodeInternally()` is exactly how the UI is updated. It updates the contents and state of many `View`s. It is up to Android to reflect these changes and redraw the UI. Apps don't somehow redraw their own `View`s.

Comment: I get it, it's the basic knowledge of the android system. thanks for your help, have a good day :)